# PHP or JavaScript presentation library for articles

Tags: php, javascript, latex

Is there some good library written in PHP or JavaScript to present articles? It would be cool to have Latex-style syntax or some similar markup language and provide nice looking styles. For example in text:

```
\section{Some section}
\label{sec:label}

This is paragraph~\ref{sec:label}.
```

It would generate HTML code like:

```
<h3>1. Some section</h3>

This is paragraph 1.
```

Comment: If you really want all that, why not just use LaTeX to generate a PDF, and embed the file?

Comment: do you means like using templates? [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) is a good option

Comment: smarty is a PHP to html, not Mark(up/down) to HTML :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some regex. Make something similar to a BBCode parser or Markdown (as on Stackoverflow).

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you want to use a template engine for this.
There are many different template engines for PHP. The most popular is [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

There are also many others to choose from at this [list](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/).

Comment: what, did I miss something, I don't think he wanted template engine ?

Comment: Maybe I missed something, surely you can use a template engine to render content provided by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same system as what GitHub and Stack overflow uses, it's called markdown and it comes in a variety of languages.

you can view information here: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

and you can download the libraries here http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/